# Break out of nested for loop without using break statement

Tags: java, nested-loops

I want to break out of a nested for loop **without** using the `break` statement. The reason for this is that I get a problem later in my program when using the `break` statement.

The source code is this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++){
    for (int j = 10; j < 100; j++) {
        code;
        if (code == true) {
            :break out here:
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: j=100 (or i=100, whereever you want to break)

Comment: What would be the problem with break later on?

Comment: Instead of trying to find some ugly hack to avoid using a `break` statement, explain what your *real* problem is - what problem would you be getting when you would use `break`?

Comment: Are you aware of the break with labels? Cause it can break out of a nested loop in just one statement.

Comment: I am using totaly 4 nested loops to mark 4 different points in an image. But when I am finished with the first nested loop, the program wouldnt go over to the next one. The break statement Ive been using is: 

outerloop:
for(){
for(){
code: 
if(code==true){
break outerloop;}}}

Comment: @user3176870 This should be part of original post, rather then comment. Especially because there is code example in it. Please [edit] your question and move your comment there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++){
  for (int j = 10; j < 100; j++) {
      //code;
      if(code == true){
         j = 100; //will cancel the inner for loop.
      }
  }
}
```

Comment: What if break from both the loops?

Comment: just add `i = 100;` into the `if` statement.

Comment: Or use break with label otherwise your code is messy as you need to ensure that you set i and j to the right numbers.

Comment: @Sk8erPeter: The question was to break a loop with a break. Of course I would write a break myself.

Answer (score 1):

That's one of the few case where a goto statement wouldn' t be terrible. Better yet, extract the loops into another method and use return statement, as @S R SH mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

Try doing this, it's quite simple.

```
boolean flag = true;
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++){
    for (int j = 10; j < 100; j++) {
        code;
        if (code == true) {
            j = 101; //any value that would make the condition check in for loop false
            flag = false;
        }
     }
     if (flag==false) {
         i = 101;   //any value that would make the condition check in for loop false
     }
}
```

Comment: Quite simple? Try using break with label and you don't need the extra flags.

Comment: It also wouldn't compile as you can't assign 0 and 1 to a Boolean.

Comment: Apologies. I meant true and false by saying 1 and 0.

Answer (score 1):

Another possibility is to use a boolean flag, that is added to the condition in the for-loops.

```
boolean breakOut = false;
for (int i = 0; i < 100 && !breakOut; i++) {
    for (int j = 10; j < 100 && !breakOut; j++) {
        code;
        if (code == true) {
            breakOut = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

make i and/or j more than 100 depending on the loop you want to break

Answer (score 0):

Change it on this.

```
    public void firstFor(int index){
      for(int i =index; i<100;i++){
      secondFor();
      }
  }
    public void secondFor(){
      for(int j=0;j<100;j++){
    //your code...
       if(code==true) return;

      }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Put your code block in a separate method and use return.  It will be the cleanest approach.

Answer (score 0):

You can use label:

```
  firstLabel: for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
            secondLabel: for (int j = 10; j < 100; j++) {
                System.out.println("J = " + j);
                if (j == 50) {
                    break firstLabel;
                }
            }
        }
```